# How to Execute Role Inside the Ansible Blocks

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have written a ansible playbook which do a deployment on the remote machines

```
-   name: Deployment part of the script
    vars:
       hostName: 
       build_num: 
    hosts: "{{hostName}}"
    become: true
    serial: 1
    tasks: this does deployment
```

after this I want to execute the util which is on localhost from where this playbook will be executed.

Now I have written a roles which does this for me if I execute them separately as a playbook

```
  - name: Roles Demo
    hosts: 127.0.0.1
    connection: local
    vars: 
       var1: "sometextvalue"
       var2: "sometextvalue"
       var3: "someurl" 
    roles: 
    - demorole #role which I created
```

Now I want to integrate the role in my main playbook mentioned at the top but I am getting

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.
```

although its the same snippet which is working fine when run individually

Also I wanted to execute this using "Ansible blocks" like when a certain condition is matched execute a certain role but for that also I am getting the same above error just to summarize what I want to achieve using the blocks is as below

```
-   name: Deployment part of the script
    vars:
       hostName: 
       build_num: 
    hosts: "{{hostName}}"
    become: true
    serial: 1
    tasks: this does deployment complete
- name: Task for Doing some check
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars:
      var1: "dakdkadadakdhkahdkahkdh
      var2: "jdjaldjlaj"
      var3: "djasjdlajdlajdljadljaldjlaj"
  block: 
  - name: Doing Check for some1
    roles: 
    - role1
  when: x == "somevalue1"
- block: 
  - name: Doing check for some2
    roles: 
    - role2
  when: x == "somevalue2"
.
.
.
assuming the vars value are same
```

so I am not sure if this could be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a block outside of the tasks section is not valid.

You can however execute roles from within the tasks section, which will allow you to use blocks and `when` conditionals however you choose.

Example:

```
- name: Task for Doing some check
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  vars:
      var1: "dakdkadadakdhkahdkahkdh
      var2: "jdjaldjlaj"
      var3: "djasjdlajdlajdljadljaldjlaj"
  tasks:
    - name: Doing Check for some1
      import_role:
        name: role1
      when: x == "somevalue1"
```

You will need to decide whether to use `import_role` or `include_role`. Take a look at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse.html#dynamic-vs-static for an explanation of the differences.